# GA Tracking Code

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have never used Adwords or Analytics before...

I have Adwords and Analytics and I have one multilanguage site. I have 2 goals that you reach after posting certain forms. All forms and "thank you" pages are in all languages. Should I use one tracking code for all "thank you" pages or should I create one for every language? If I should create one for every language, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only create one tracking code for all pages
what you can do is track language for each page as a content group/custom dimension and send it to google analytics.

Here's how you can create custom dimensions and content groups
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.